# How to make a string literal in php sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a query like this. This one came from a text box. Because of the <kbd>'</kbd> in <kbd>it's</kbd> it closes the string.

I don't want to trap it in the text box. Because I need to allow the text box to write anything the user want as reason.

I tried to put @ before the variable. But it seems it does not work like C# where putting @ before a string makes it literal.

I know this is also vulnerable to injection. But if the solution has also to do with injection might as well hit two birds in one stone. But if its possible to solve just the escaping the characters that will do.

```
$_GETVARS['txtReason'] = "'it's already there, in droves.'";

UPDATE tablename SET reason_for_exception='".$_GETVARS['txtReason']."' WHERE ID='1'
```

Comment: my bad.. it was  mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Can you show me how? Because the variable there will come from a variable. So the user can enter: it's or its based on his decision.

Comment: how about putting the values of the string in a variable and sanitize the variable before putting it there..

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reason_for_exception = mysql_real_escape_string("your text here");

UPDATE tablename SET reason_for_exception= "$reason_for_exception" WHERE ID='1'
```

how about that?

Comment: Thanks this is what I need. It added the needed / in the string.

Will this also prevent sql injections? Or that is another story?

Comment: yes it will also.. but this is deprecated.. I think you need to go with mysqli. =) happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try below Query, and it would be better to use Stored procedure, this type of issues will not be occurred there.

```
UPDATE tablename SET reason_for_exception='it''s already there, in droves.' WHERE ID='1'
```

or if you want to Continue with normal Query then store that string into some string variable and then try, might be helpful to you.

Like

```
$_GETVARS['txtReason' = "it's already there, in droves.";

UPDATE tablename SET reason_for_exception='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GETVARS['txtReason')."' WHERE ID='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

for this wrap your content in mysqli_real_escape_string()

> for reference [Mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$_GETVARS['txtReason' = "it's already there, in droves.";
UPDATE tablename SET reason_for_exception='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GETVARS['txtReason')."' WHERE ID='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to escape the string for SQL input.

Not sure what you're using to build your queries but you may want to look into using prepared statements if you're not already. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)